# linq query to find distinct combinations of list items taking 2 at a time c#

Tags: c#, linq, combinations

```
var com = from exam1 in timeTable.Exams
          from exam2 in timeTable.Exams
          where (exam1 != exam2)
          select new List<Exam> { exam1, exam2 };
```

timeTable is a list of Exams

How can i get com to be distinct no matter what the order of the exams are that it contains. I think it is doing permutations now i need only distinct combinations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var exams = timeTable.Exams.ToList();

var com = exams.Select(x => exams.Where(y => exams.IndexOf(y) > exams.IndexOf(x))
    .Select(z => new List<Exam> {x, z}))
    .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: Just fix the typo on Line 2, it should be List<string>

Comment: I like how simple you keep the code and still maintain brevity

Comment: I think this is `O(n^2)` when `O(n)` is possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you can implement a comparison such as `IComparable<Exam>` (which could, for example, compare based on a key field such as `ExamId`), you could possibly do it like this (showing example using integers)

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

var query = from item1 in array
            from item2 in array
            where (item1.CompareTo(item2) < 0)
            select new Tuple<int, int>(item1, item2);

foreach (Tuple<int, int> tuple in query)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
```

Without implementing an interface, the same logic could be expressed as a `Func<>` inline or declared seperately, depending on how complicated the logic might be.

```
Func<int, int, int> itemComparer = (x, y) => x.CompareTo(y);
// in your case, perhaps 
// Func<Exam, Exam, int> examComparer = (exam1, exam2) => exam1.Id.CompareTo(exam2.Id);

var query = from item1 in array
            from item2 in array
            where itemComparer(item1, item2) < 0
            select new Tuple<int, int>(item1, item2);
```

Otherwise, you might consider going by indexes and only looking at `item2` when its position within the sequence is greater than `item1`.

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

var query = from item1 in array.Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
            from item2 in array.Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
            where (item1.index < item2.index)
            select new Tuple<int, int>(item1.item, item2.item);

foreach (Tuple<int, int> tuple in query)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
```

Comment: It's not always possible to define a linear ordering in any pratical way.

Answer (score 0):

First define a class that represents an unordered tuple:

```
class UnorderedTuple<T1, T2> {
    public T1 Item1 { get; set; }
    public T2 Item2 { get; set; }
    public UnorderedTuple(T1 item1, T2 item2) {
        this.Item1 = item1;
        this.Item2 = item2;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) {
            return true;
        }
        UnorderedTuple<T1, T2> instance = obj as UnorderedTuple<T1, T2>;
        if (instance == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return (this.Item1.Equals(instance.Item1) &&
                this.Item2.Equals(instance.Item2)) ||
               (this.Item1.Equals(instance.Item2) &&
                this.Item2.Equals(instance.Item1)
               );
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return this.Item1.GetHashCode() ^ this.Item2.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then, as an example:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

var pairs = from item1 in array
            from item2 in array
            where item1 != item2
            select new UnorderedTuple<int, int>(item1, item2);

var distinct = pairs.Distinct();
foreach (var item in distinct) {
    Console.WriteLine("{{{0}, {1}}}", item.Item1, item.Item2);
}
```

Now you will only see the pair `{1, 2}` once. Note that

```
Console.WriteLine(distinct.Count());
```

outputs `36` which is correct because there are `9 * 8 / 2 = 72 / 2 = 36` unique combinations (`9 * 8` represents the number of ordered pairs with distinct elements, and we divide by `2` to get the number of unordered pairs).

For your specific case:

```
var com = (from exam1 in timeTable.Exams
           from exam2 in timeTable.Exams
           where (exam1 != exam2)
           select new UnorderedTuple<Exam, Exam>(exam1, exam2)
          ).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var com = exams
          .Select(i => new {Head = new [] {i}, Tail = exams.SkipWhile(j => j != i).Skip(1)})
          .Select(l => l.Head.Join(l.Tail, x => 0, x => 0, (a,b) => new {a,b}))
          .SelectMany(l => l);
```

How this works: (for sequence 1,2,3,4)
**Step 1:** Segregate the input sequence into a head list and a tail list. A head list will always contain one element and the tail list will contain elements after the head element.
 (result: {[1],[2,3,4]}, {[2],[3,4]}, {[3], [4]}, {[], []})
**Step 2:** Join the head and the tail lists.
 (result: [[1,2],[1,3], [1,4]], [[2,3],[2,4]], [[3,4]]) 
**Step 3:** Flatten the collection

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var array = timeTable.Exams.ToArray();
var twoTuples = from index1 in Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length)
                from index2 in Enumerable.Range(i, array.Length - i)
                select Tuple.Create(array[index1], array[index2]);
```

(Of course, you can replace the tuple with an anonymous type or a  `List<Exam`> if necessary, but I thought this was clearer).

If you don't want `(x, x)`, one way would be to add a `where index1 != index2` clause, or alternatively, change the ranges.

Also, if you only want "distinct" tuples (the sequence contains duplicates), you can add a `.Distinct()` call at the end. This will work fine since  the `Tuple<,>` type overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode` sensibly.

**Advantages**:

1. Doesn't require any intrinsic comparability of the source items.
2. Doesn't needlessly consider and then reject combinations.

**Drawback**:

This is just a fancy way of writing a nested for-loop with indices. Focuses on indices rather than on items, so it is debatably not very LINQy.